# SQL COMMAND + CASE Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, sqlcommand

I am having a an issue with `SQL` Command and `CASE`. I am pretty new to Crystal Reports/SQL and I have a basic code that I am playing around with to learn. I want to clean out a field -- that has imported from `SQL Server`. I just want to do something simple like this:

```
SELECT  "I"."I_TYPE", "Alleg”  =
CASE  
    WHEN "ALLEGs"."ALLEG”  LIKE ‘*im*’ THEN ‘Improper’
    ELSE ‘UNKNOWN’
END
```

I get an error that says Database Connector Error:

```
'42000:[MS][SQL..Incorrect syntax near ' . ' . Databse vender code 102.
```

Can you even use `CASE` as an `IF THEN` statement in the SQL Command. I am aware of SQL expressions, but I am trying to pull data to sql command to prevent performance decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about crystal report but your query formation don't look correct. It should be

```
SELECT I.I_TYPE, 
CASE WHEN ALLEGs.ALLEG LIKE '%im%' THEN 'Improper' ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END AS 'Alleg'
```

Comment: I think you need the `%`: `LIKE '%im%'`

Comment: great I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, is correct for direct SQL commands to the server.
However sometimes when running Crystal Reports we use VBA within the report to do some data tuning rather than modifying the raw SQL on the fly.

This leaves the raw SQL a known result (verifiable on the SQL Server) and then modify the output in Crystal to fit the end users filtering requirements.

This is not efficient with large result sets but when the results are smaller (under 50k records) we usually have our team go with simple (post filtering) to reduce design and testing time.
This technique works very well with dynamic filters on the option section.

example: [Record Selection]

```
if {?Select Sales Person} <> "ENT" then
    {R0033___P2A.ProjectionSP} = {?Select Sales Person} and {R0033___P2A.FM} >= 0
else
    {R0033___P2A.ProjectionSP} > ""  and {R0033___P2A.FM} >= 0
```

Where {?Select Sales Person} is a user selection filter and {R0033___P2A} is a predefined report view or stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will keep this in mind.